# Unity dotween delay before the next append not working

Tags: unity-game-engine, dotween

I have lists of data and I am trying to tween them by sequence. If I put a delay for each of the tween it will not work. What I try to achieve is inserting the delay before the next sequence.

```
private IEnumerator<float> _CameraTransition()
{
    var camSequence = DOTween.Sequence();

    for (int i = 0; i < CamerasData.Count; i++)
        camSequence.Append(cam.DOFieldOfView(CamerasData[i].fov, CamerasData[i].duration).SetDelay(CamerasData[i].triggerDelay));

    camSequence.Play();
    yield return 0;
}
```

If I remove the `SetDelay` it works, but of course no delay

Comment: While not relevant to your problem: this function, as you've written it, does not need to be a coroutine. Your `yield` instruction is the last statement, meaning that no code is left to execute after the coroutine continues afterwards.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

(NOTE: I'm the developer of the library the OP is talking about)

The correct way to add delays inside a Sequence is to use [AppendInterval](http://dotween.demigiant.com/documentation.php?api=AppendInterval) on the Sequence itself.

```
for (int i = 0; i < CamerasData.Count; i++) {
   camSequence
      .AppendInterval(CamerasData[i].triggerDelay)
      .Append(cam.DOFieldOfView(CamerasData[i].fov, CamerasData[i].duration));
}
```

That said, SetDelay should also work in theory, even if it's not recommended. I will add it to my to-check list.